# convex, smooth but not analytic

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am interested to know an example of real convex function which is infinitely differentiable but not (real) analytic. Is this kind of example exists? If yes please suggest me. If not please let me know the argument.

Comment: Lower half of the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you show no effort, I will not give a complete answer but rather a hint:

You perhaps know that the function
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2}  & x\neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
is infinitely many times differentiable but not real analytic (one has $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\geq 0$ but $g$ is not constant $0$). The problem is that this function $g$ is not convex.

Perhaps the convexity issue is solved if we multiply $g$ by $x^2$? I suggest that you try with
$$
f(x)=g(x)x^2.
$$

Comment: Yes I was aware of "g". But I did not know how to bring convexity on that function. Thank you. @mickep.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think your problem is solved, you might accept my answer. That way, the problem will not appear anymore in the list of "open" questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would let $g(x)$ be the "$e^{-1/x}$ function" and then for any $C>0$ define

$$f_C(x) = Cx^2 + g(x).$$

We then have $f_C''(x) = 2C+ g''(x).$ Since $g''$ is bounded on $\mathbb R,$ it's clear that $C$ can be chosen so that $f_C''(x) > 0$ everywhere. For such a $C,$ $f_C$ is $C^\infty,$ strictly convex, and not real analytic on $\mathbb R.$